# Connecting an Ubuntu 18.04 VM to a Virtual Box Nat Network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I'm trying to set up a network of virtual machines using a VirtualBox Nat Network. Some vms, specifically a cluster of coreos boxes and metasploitable, connect just fine. Others, specifically any Ubuntu vm that I've set up myself do not.

The nat network is set up as follows

```
$ VBoxManage natnetwork list fabian
NAT Networks:

Name:        fabian
Network:     172.17.8.0/24
Gateway:     172.17.8.1
IPv6:        No
Enabled:     Yes
```

What I've tried is to edit the Ubuntu vms `/etc/network/interfaces` file to read as such

```
# interface(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

(this is based in part on the `/etc/network/interfaces` file from metasploitable, which is an ubuntu based vm that seems to connect to the network just fine)

However, when I try to run `$ sudo systemctl restart networking` it hangs and times out. I've included the output of `$ journalctl -xe` below. There are entries from before what I've included, but they seem to be the same message with different intervals.

Is there something I'm missing in connecting setting up the network interface?

```
Oct 23 10:22:49 burp-vm systemd-resolved[290]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 23 10:22:52 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:22:52 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:22:54 burp-vm systemd-resolved[290]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
Oct 23 10:23:12 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:12 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:21 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:21 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:30 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:30 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:42 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:42 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:54 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:23:54 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:05 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:05 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:20 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:20 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:39 burp-vm systemd-resolved[290]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 23 10:24:39 burp-vm systemd-resolved[290]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
Oct 23 10:24:41 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:41 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:48 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:24:48 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:00 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:00 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:10 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:10 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:22 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:22 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:33 burp-vm dhclient[1889]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:33 burp-vm ifup[1867]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6914771e)
Oct 23 10:25:35 burp-vm systemd[1]: networking.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 23 10:25:35 burp-vm systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Oct 23 10:25:35 burp-vm systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 23 10:25:35 burp-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Ubuntu 17.10 the `ifupdown` is considered a deprecated tool and replaced by `netplan` . To use the `/etc/network/interfaces` the `ifupdown` package should be installed.

In your case you should configure the network using the `netplan` tool:

The configuration file can be found under `/etc/netplan/` . Create/edit the `*.yaml` file as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

If you have the Network-Manager installed you can replace `renderer: networkd` with `renderer: NetworkManager`

Then run:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

See:

[Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples)

[Migrating To Netplan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MigratingToNetplan)